# Pre-Flintstones Caveman Comedy Short Story

Tags: story-identification

I read this amusing tale - in an American anthology of otherwise serious SF stories - in the 1960s. I checked the copyright and it pre-dated the 'Flintstones' by several years - can't remember just how many. Like 'The Flintstones' it featured cave people who act and talk like modern folk. In one scene the MC visits a famous artist who has painted an abstract on his cave wall. Famous Artist: "I call this 'The Soul Of Man'." MC (who doesn't get it at all): "I guess it does look like a foot." That is all I can remember - the exact plot and the ending escapes me. I have wondered ever since if Hanna-Barbara got their idea from this story.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Age of Invention](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53924) by Norman Spinrad. I read it in [Perilous Planets](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25909) but that was published in 1980 so you must have read it in an earlier anthology.

It starts:

> One morning, having nothing better to do, I went to visit my cousin Roach. Roach lived in one of those lizard-infested caves on the East Side of the mountain. Roach did not hunt bears. Roach did not grow grain. Roach spent his daylight hours throwing globs of bearfat, bison-chips and old rotten plants against the walls of his cave. Roach said that he was an Artist. He said it with a capital 'A'. (Even though writing has not yet been invented.)

The pun is this section:

> On the nearest wall of the cave, there was this big blob of bearfat. In the middle of it was this small piece of bison-chip. Red and green and brown plant stains surrounded this. It smelt as good as it looked.
>
> 'Uh... interesting..." I said.
>
> 'Like a masterpiece, baby,' Roach said proudly. 'I call it "The Soul of Man".'
>
> 'Uh... "The Sole of Man" ? Er... it does sort of look like a foot.'
>
> 'No, no, man! Soul not sole!'
>
> But Roach, spelling hasn't been invented yet.'
>
> Sorry. I forgot.'

Comment: That is the story! Thanks for the quick response and happy new year!

Comment: And I was wrong - it post-dated 'The Flintstones'!

Comment: oh dear spelling out the puns for the reader and everything